# Debug JQuery - Not working in Code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make this code work but after trying a lot I am still unable to run it. The image should animate but its not working. Any ideas whats wrong? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type=""
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
img
{
    position:absolute;
}​

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $zombie = $('img#flickr');


          function runit(){

            $zombie
             .animate({ opacity: 1 },100)
                .animate({top:'300px',left:'300px'}, {duration:2000})
            .animate({top:'260px',left:'340px'}, {duration:2000})
            .animate({top:'220px', left:'380px'}, {duration:2000})
            .animate({top:'180px', left:'420px'}, {duration:2000})
            .animate({top:'140px', left:'460px'}, {duration:2000})
                .animate({top:'100px', left:'500px'}, 2000,function(){
                   runit();    
                });

        }


        runit();​
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--<img id ="flickr" src="9.png" />
-->
<img id ="flickr" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider putting this up on http://jsFiddle.net/ so we can play with it. Also there is a HTML markup error in the `<head></head>`: `<script type=""`

Comment: its working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/btLhP/1/

Comment: and here http://jsfiddle.net/JcGuX/

Comment: @RickKuipers: I agree, its working on `jsFiddle` but not in the real world. I have uploaded it to my blog:http://apptec.net/test2 but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Its](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/btLhP/1/)** working just fine. There is broken `<script type=""` in your code, remove it. But it works for mine with that broken tag. If still there is problem, then use `firebug` or such type debugger to check error.

- Check that jquery is loading correctly or not.
- Take your `<script>` having code just before `</body>`, though may be its not an issue.

#### Go to the js code where you call the function `runit();`, place cursor after `;` and press `backspace` key until it delete the semicolon(`;`) and save the script, upload it and check again.

Comment: I used Firebug to check it and came to know that the jquery is not working on the `img` tag

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/B9z92/

In your code example, you have the tag fragment `<script type=""`. Perhaps that is your issue?

What behavior are you experiencing? Are you getting any javascript errors?

EDIT: Looks like you are getting the error "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on line 37. Did you copy/paste some of that code from somewhere? Try and delete all of the whitespace after the call to `runit()` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: The error says: Uncaught syntax error Unexpected token illegal.